# Ruby deep_merge on an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I want to merge an attribute on hashes nested inside an array, which is nested inside a hash.

```
ball = {
  name: "Hugh",
  colors: [
    {name: "Blue"},
    {name: "Red"}
  ]
}
```

I tried to use [deep merge](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge), but I think it only supports merging into a nested hash, not an array of hashes.

```
balls.deep_merge(size: "small")
```

Output:

```
ball = {
  name: "Hugh",
  colors: [
    {name: "Blue"},
    {name: "Red"}
  ],
  size: "small"
}
```

Expected output.

```
ball = {
  name: "Hugh",
  colors: [
    {name: "Blue", size: "small"},
    {name: "Red", size: "small"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the array (depending on how abstract you need it to be).

```
ball[:colors].each {|c| c[:size] = "small"}
```

Or, assuming you have a "balls" array, this would work for mass assignment.

```
balls.each {|ball| ball[:colors].each {|c| c[:size] = "small"} }
```

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing that can do this automagically, I'm afraid. There is no way for a program to know that `{ size: "small" }` is meant to go into each hash of the `colors` key and not in any other.

But you've got a good start here formulated the question almost as a unit test, so I have no doubt you can find a manual way to do this with TDD!

Comment: I doubt this is worthy of an answer, should be more of a comment